# convertview listview adapter EditText confuse

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter, convertview

I have a listView filled with a custum class extends BaseAdapter

```
 private List<Bundle> allTipologiaInsetti = ....;
 listView.setAdapter(new CustumAdapter(getBaseContext(), allTipologiaInsetti, this));
```

Then on my Adapter..

```
public class CustumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public CustumAdapter (Context context, List<Bundle> items, RaccoltaDatiQuestions activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    //update
    map = new HashMap<Number, String>();

}
...
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Bundle myObj = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tipologia_insetti_item, null);
        holder.campoNum = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numField);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    //UPDATE
    String num = map.get(position);
    if(num!=null && !num.equals("")){
        holder.campoNum.setText(num + "");
    }else {
        holder.campoNum.setText(myObj.getInt("num") + "");
    }


    holder.campoNum.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(holder.campoNum, position));

}

        public GenericTextWatcher(EditText campNum, int position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.campoNum = campNum;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {  }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (campoNum.getText().length() > 0) {
            if (campoNum.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
                Bundle myObj = items.get(position);
                myObj.putInt("num", Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
               //UPDATE
                map.put(position, s.toString());

            }
        }

    }
}
```

"campoNum" is an editText:

I change on first Item of list the value of "campoNum" (and it's work well), but if I scroll down, some other items of list, keep the same value of first item....

I try to analyze it and I discover that:

if I have 3 Items visible on list, and I change the first item, the 5th will take the same value of first, if I have 4 items visible if I change the first, will change also the 6th... etc..

If I remove "if (view == null )"  and I let's inflate the view everytime, the problem is solved!

If I well understand: every time one Item of list is hidden (the first one) it will be used for the new appearing item (the 5th one) and the convertVIew passed on the fifth item is the same of first one

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

yeah well that's how listviews work. as you scroll up/down items get reprinted to their original layout and data. I had the exact same issue with changing an items Icon color.

A work around is using an array e.g array item `myText= ""` for all your listview items. The position of the array item is the same as the position of the item in a listview.

in your getView when you add text to editText store it to the myText in the array.

The all you need to do, again in the getView is say

`if myText is not empty`, `add myText to the items editText`. you do this all by code.

as you scroll up/down now it will fill in the text for any items editText with the stored Text e.g myText

You use this method for just about anything you want to change for an item in a listview. Icons, text, etc.

So store something in the array to represent the state or Data change for an Item and then Set it as you scroll.

All this is done inside the `getView`

Comment: maybe I don't undertand... ( your suggestion is almost a what I already did?!... I read the value from Bundle myObj = items.get(position); and set when the value change: myObj.putInt("num", Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));

Comment: @Crifano Stefano. You are doing it here (afterTextChanged) and i dont think that's going to work. You will need to store the Text eg in an array and then add the Stored array text to the Items

Answer (score 0):

when you put value in your edittext, put that value in  hashmap along with the position (AS a key for value) and every time when you r Edittext is displayed then you should get value from that hashmap on the position key,
 if exist.

```
public CustumAdapter (Context context, List<Bundle> items, RaccoltaDatiQuestions activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    //update
    map = new HashMap<Number, String>();

}
...
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Bundle myObj = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tipologia_insetti_item, null);
        holder.campoNum = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numField);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    //UPDATE
    String num = map.get(position);
    if(num!=null && !num.equals("")){
        holder.campoNum.setText(num + "");
    }else {
        holder.campoNum.setText(myObj.getInt("num") + "");
    }
if (map.containsKey(position)){

        holder.campoNum.setText(map.get(position));
}

    holder.campoNum.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(holder.campoNum, position));

}

        public GenericTextWatcher(EditText campNum, int position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.campoNum = campNum;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {  }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (campoNum.getText().length() > 0) {

                map.put(position, campoNum.getText().toString());


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, where I need to initialize the HashMap? on the costructor?

Comment: something still missing for me. I think both answers are good, I edit my question, with the map, but still not works! Maybe I need to store the map outside of my custumAdapter? and I don't see the different to use the map instead of Bundle myObj = items.get(position)